# Dropdown list selected index returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web page that generates an incident report in a database. The incident report is tied to a car table using car ID.

When I click the submit button I get an error in the DAL that reads "Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CarID', table 'RideXpress.dbo.IncidentReport'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."

The relevant aspx code is as follows

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DD1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

The relevant code behind file follows

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RideXpressConnectionString"].ToString();
            ReportBLL ReportBL = new ReportBLL(connectionString);
            ReportViewModel report = new ReportViewModel();
            int ID = DD1.SelectedIndex;
            report.CarID = ID;
            report.DateOfIncident = Convert.ToDateTime(Date.Text);
            report.ReportName = Name.Text;
            report.ReportDescription = Description.Text;
            report.DateOfReport = DateTime.Today;
            ReportBL.AddReport(report);
            Response.Redirect("~/Reports.aspx");
```

and the DAL, where the error is raised follows

```
public int AddReport(ReportViewModel add)
    {
        string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO IncidentReport(DateOfIncident, ReportName, ReportDescription, DateOfReport)" +
            "Values (@DateOfIncident, @ReportName, @ReportDescription, @DateOfReport)";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (sqlQuery, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReportID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = add.ReportID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CarID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = add.CarID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfIncident", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = add.DateOfIncident;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReportName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = add.ReportName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReportDescription", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = add.ReportDescription;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfReport", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = add.DateOfReport;
            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your ReportId is NULL. You have not initialized it or assigned a value to it. Secondly, your insert statement does not include it and nor it includes the CarID. Is ReportID an identity column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the query to

```
string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO IncidentReport(CarID,DateOfIncident, ReportName, ReportDescription, DateOfReport)" +
        "Values (@CarID,@DateOfIncident, @ReportName, @ReportDescription, @DateOfReport)";
```

Also ReportId is not in the query so it would not get set, either add it to the query like I did carID above or if it is identity auto increment don't set it at all.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been banging my head against the wall for 45 mins, just for this tiny error. reportID is Identity auto increment

Comment: dumb question, but how do I do that? (Sorry for being such a noob)

Comment: np, under the up/down arrows for the answer if you cursor right under it a check should display, click it.